# Signing a java applet with an spc file from GoDaddy

Tags: java, applet, code-signing

I'm trying to sign a java applet using an spc file from godaddy.  Here's the command I'm using:

`keytool -import -keystore codesignstore -storepass [pass] -alias [alias] -file [filename]`

Unfortunately, running this command returns

`keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Input not an X.509 certificate`

I talked to GoDaddy and they assure me that it is indeed a valid X.509 certificate and otherwise provided 0 help.  Anyone know how to make this work?  I've read a few comments that suggest that the problem might be the alias, but we've tried the alias we specified when creating the CSR as well as the one specified in GoDaddy.  In addition, some note that the problem may be related to this java bug: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4874076.  However, I don't see any odd URLs in the spc of the type they note in that bug report.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I don't know what was causing the error, I was able to get through the signing process by properly following [GoDaddy's instructions](http://help.godaddy.com/article/4780).  We originally generated our own CSR and then jumped into GoDaddy's instructions part of the way through.  For others with this problem that have problems reading/following instructions, save yourself the headache and start over again following the steps that GoDaddy outlines.

Comment: I've tried following GoDaddy's instructions, but they do a "keytool -import" of a cert file.  I can't seem to figure out how they get that cert file.  I tried downloading the PEM file from the web site, but that gives me a "Incomplete certificate chain in reply" error.

Comment: You create one in step 2 from the instructions above.

Comment: Would love to have some sense of why this answer has been voted down.

Comment: @Josh Me too, but what was the actual difference in the process? You generated your own CSR but that's what they tell you to do anyway.

Comment: I'm pretty far removed from this at this point, but I think what happened is that I generated the CSR a different way (i.e., with different options) rather than using their precise instructions.

Answer (score 1):

If you open up that spc file, you can export the certificates as X.509, in Windows with certmgr.msc

Answer (score 1):

GoDaddy lets you download a `.zip` file containing a `.spc` file.
what is not evident is that an `.spc` file is just a PKCS#7 certificate chain, they can easily be extracted using:

```
openssl pkcs7 -inform der -in *.spc -print_certs
```