# How to sign a Jar with a Godaddy Cert Pem file?

Tags: java, ssl, applet

I have a java applet that needed signing, so I went with GoDaddy and bought a code signing certificate.

I followed this [tutorial](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/4780/signing-java-code) I created a keystore and a CSR. And GoDaddy replied with the PEM file. This is where I am getting confused. According to the tutorial, I should have a PKCS#7 for step 3. This is not a PEM file. I have examined the PEM file in KeyStore Explorer and it seems to have the public and private key attached to it. I followed [this stack thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21289619/3140664), and still could not get it working. The error is:

```
jarsigner: Certificate chain not found for: podScan.  podScan must reference a 
valid KeyStore key entry containing a private key and corresponding public 
key certificate chain.
```

This error appeared when I did the last step of Howard's post.

Any thoughts on what to do?

Comment: This is a *Link-Only Question* :) You should add the commands you used, and not send folks offsite to some blog.

Comment: Bruno shows you how to dump your keystore and verify it has the proper certs at [Why doesn't Java send the client certificate during SSL handshake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9299133/why-doesnt-java-send-the-client-certificate-during-ssl-handshake/9300727).